# Approach to make a C++ - MySql Connection

Tags: c++, mysql, connection, database-connection

I am new to MySql - C++ connection. I looked for some tutorials and came across ones similar to [this](http://www.codingfriends.com/index.php/2010/02/17/mysql-connection-example/) i.e. ones using `mysql_real_connect`

```
MYSQL* connect;
connect = mysql_int(NULL);
mysql_real_connect(connect,NULL,"UserName","Password","DatabaseName",0,NULL,0);
```

But the [tutorial page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/connector-cpp-examples-complete-example-2.html) of MySql uses `Driver`,`Connection` approach*.

```
driver = get_driver_instance();
con = driver->connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:3306", "root", "root");
```

<sub>(*Looks like database connections done in Java)</sub>

**What is the difference between these two techniques?**

*I googled a bit but I dont seem to get relevant results(Might be possible I dont know what to google about)*

**Update:**

I had a proper look at the manual pages on [dev.mysql.com](http://dev.mysql.com/). It seems `mysql_real_connect` and other similar functions are actually part of the [MySql C Api](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/c-api-functions.html) and `Driver`, `Connection`, etc are part of the [MySql C++ Api](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-cpp/en/connector-cpp.html) . Is there any problem in using `MySql C Api` in C++ Code (found lot of  example codes with this) or is it safe and wise and keep to `MySql C++ Api` for C++ programs